# Python Regex to create a new column but TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am trying to use python regex to look at values in Visit_Type and match it to a list of strings. This would create a new column df['Visit_Grouping'] . There are so many one offs of Visit Type, I thought that .search or .findall would help provide some normalization.

I would like 'CCheck', 'CCHECKSCHEDPAST', 'CCHECKSCHEDPASTSCHEDPAST' to match with C CHECK and 'BRIDGE',    'BRIDGESCHEDPAST' to match with BRIDGE.

However I am getting the following error.

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Here is a sample of the code.

```
# import packages
# python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import tempfile
import pymssql
import tempfile

# initialize data of lists.
data = {'ID': ['089', '983', '037', '654', '592', '243', '985'],
        'Visit_Type': ['AGING', 'BCKPACKAGE',   'BRIDGE',   'BRIDGESCHEDPAST',  'CCHECK',   'CCHECKSCHEDPAST',  'CCHECKSCHEDPASTSCHEDPAST']}
 
# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['rank1',
                               'rank2',
                               'rank3',
                               'rank4',
                               'rank5',
                               'rank6',
                               'rank7',])


visit_lst = ["AGING","GEAR", "B CHECK", "BRIDGE","C CHECK", "C2 CHECK" , "FDA", "FINLET","H CHECK", "GEAR", "IFC", "L CHECK", "L2 CHECK", "M2 CHECK", "RV", "SLAT TRACK", "SV", "TR", "WEIGH"]


df['Visit_Grouping']  = re.search(r"(?=("+'|'.join(visit_lst)+r"))", df["Visit_Type"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that re.search expects a single string as the second argument, but you're passing a pandas Series (df["Visit_Type"]). To apply the regex operation to each element in the 'Visit_Type' column, you should use the str accessor to apply the regex operation element-wise. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'ID': ['089', '983', '037', '654', '592', '243', '985'],
        'Visit_Type': ['AGING', 'BCKPACKAGE', 'BRIDGE', 'BRIDGESCHEDPAST', 'CCHECK', 'CCHECKSCHEDPAST', 'CCHECKSCHEDPASTSCHEDPAST']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4', 'rank5', 'rank6', 'rank7',])

visit_lst = ["AGING", "GEAR", "B CHECK", "BRIDGE", "C CHECK", "C2 CHECK", "FDA", "FINLET", "H CHECK", "GEAR", "IFC", "L CHECK", "L2 CHECK", "M2 CHECK", "RV", "SLAT TRACK", "SV", "TR", "WEIGH"]

df['Visit_Grouping'] = df['Visit_Type'].apply(lambda x: next((visit for visit in visit_lst if re.search(visit, x)), None))

print(df)

ID                Visit_Type Visit_Grouping
rank1  089                     AGING          AGING
rank2  983                BCKPACKAGE           None
rank3  037                    BRIDGE         BRIDGE
rank4  654           BRIDGESCHEDPAST         BRIDGE
rank5  592                    CCHECK           None
rank6  243           CCHECKSCHEDPAST           None
rank7  985  CCHECKSCHEDPASTSCHEDPAST           None
```